# How long have Decora switches and receptacles been manufactured?

Tags: receptacle

I found some problematic wiring in the house we just bought, and I want to establish the earliest date at which the receptacles must have been installed.  How long have Decora receptacles been widely available?  Is there a date code typically placed on receptacles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Leviton](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/SectionDisplay.jsp?section=44865&minisite=10251) Decora became popular in the 1970s.

The New York Times from February 8, 1976 (page 118) has a picture of a Decora light switch.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [registered trademark on file with the USPTO](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4802:2tripk.2.20), the "Decora" name was first used commercially in 1973.

However it's certainly possible that shape was used before the marketing name was trademarked.